# How I can display a HTML body in iOS shared Gmail app?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, gmail, uiactivityviewcontroller

I try to implement in iOS -- UIActivityViewController Gmail share subject and body, my body is in HTML format and for some reason Gmail application don't format and display this HTML, I'm getting a basic text :(

Something like:

```
<html><body style='white-space: pre-wrap;'><div
 style='font-family:verdana;font-size:10pt;'> .....
```

How I can display a HTML body in iOS shared Gmail app?

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing the same thing. Did you ever get a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your html string to NSAttributedString object rest it will take care for gmail app body.

```
NSAttributedString *strMessage = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[yourHtmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                             options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                       NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                  documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```